# DYLD: Incompatible library version for cmake

Tags: macos, dyld

OS: Mac 10.11.1

When I tried to "cmake", I got the following error message 
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/cmake
  Reason: Incompatible library version: cmake requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libexpat.1.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5

I also installed a fresh copy of CMake application, by running "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/ccmake", I got the following error message
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libTIFF.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libTIFF.dylib requires version 8.0.0 or later, but liblzma.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It now works after I commented out the dyld line in bash_profile...

Comment: This answer doesn't really help anyone: what is "the dyld line" in your bash_profile?